# case statement inside nested case

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I will make this question as more precise

I have this data

```
id   product  count  
1      a        10
1      b        20
1      c        10
1      d        30
```

I want the result like

Since both product A and B has values i want to count them as one so the result should count(distinct A,C,D) that is 3

If any of product that is (A has values but  B does not or vice versa ) then also the result has to be 3

in case both product A and B does not have value then the result should be 2

how to achieve this by using a case statement in oracle plsql

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you define `either count of a or either count of b not both`, but if you defined it explicitly then you can try this one:

```
with t as (
    select 1 as id, 'a' as product from dual
    union all
    select 1 as id, 'b' as product from dual
    union all
    select 1 as id, 'c' as product from dual
    union all
    select 1 as id, 'd' as product from dual
) select id, 
        product, 
        count( case when product in ('c', 'd', 'a') then 1 end ) --change 'a' to 'b' to get the the result for 'b'
from t
group by id, product;
```